# Google App Engine + relational database - get ID

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, relational-database

I have a question my db model looks like:

```
class UserAnswer (db.Model):
user = db.UserProperty()
name = db.StringProperty()
email = db.StringProperty()
occupation = db.IntegerProperty()
howreach = db.IntegerProperty()
rating = db.IntegerProperty()
comment = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)

class Involves(db.Model):
shortName = db.StringProperty()
fullName = db.StringProperty()

class UserInvolves(db.Model):
userAnswer = db.ReferenceProperty(UserAnswer)
involve = db.ReferenceProperty(Involves)
```

How can I do a select something like this:

```
def getInvolves(user):
results = db.GqlQuery("Select * from UserInvolves as ui where ui.userAnswer.ID='"+user.ID+"'")
```

I mean how I can get this id key? As when I try like above I recive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 517, in __call__
handler.post(*groups)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\demos\b00213576\main.py", line 217, in post
involves = getInvolves(answer)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\demos\b00213576\main.py", line 128, in getInvolves
results = db.GqlQuery("Select * from UserInvolves as ui where ui.userAnswer.ID='"+user.ID+"'")
AttributeError: 'UserAnswer' object has no attribute 'ID'
```

And I dont know how to convert to GAE :/

Comment: You can't do joins in App Engine.  You'll need to denormalize to do this kind of query.

Comment: ok but what it mean? Can You give me example??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user_answer = UserAnswer.get_by_id(user.ID)
for user_involve in user_answer.userinvolves_set:
    # these are your UserInvolves items
```

Comment: are You sure it is the same?
i can not understand why first you take user_answer and later this in for as user_answer doesnt have user_ivolve inside?

Comment: What I wrote uses a feature called back-references. From the app engine docs: ReferenceProperty has another handy feature: back-references. When a model has a ReferenceProperty to another model, each referenced entity gets a property whose value is a Query that returns all of the entities of the first model that refer to it.

Comment: ;O It is so different then normal sql still I can not understand how it is working I will try to do it like You wrote if it is back-reference 
Thank You vary much as I have to finished it today and I thought to select and print this data it will take 5 minutes and I spend much more time on it :/

Comment: I have like You wrote: 
def getInvolves(user):
 results = UserAnswer.get_by_id(user.ID)
 #db.GqlQuery("Select * from UserInvolves as ui where ui.userAnswer.ID='"+user.ID+"'")
 return results

involves = getInvolves(answer)
                    for involve in involves.involve_set:
                        self.response.out.write("<tr><td colspan='2'>'"+involve.fullName+"'</td></tr>")

And I have this error:
    involves = getInvolves(answer)
   ...in getInvolves
    results = UserAnswer.get_by_id(user.ID)
AttributeError: 'UserAnswer' object has no attribute 'ID'

Comment: In 'def getInvolves(user):' what is user? An email address? Google user object? A UserAnswer object? If it's an UserAnswer object, just use it directly: for user_involve in user.userinvolves_set

Comment: I have changed it like this:
Yes it was UserAnswer object. But I have found something like this:
http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html
But I still dont know how to take involves for any user :/ I will try to find something about inner table in Google App engine

Comment: Ok it is working! I did it like here: http://blog.arbingersys.com/2008/04/google-app-engine-better-many-to-many.html Thank You vary much for helping! I am so happy now :D And this google approach is guite interesting!